# WhatsApp Desktop App UWP not working using whatsapp://send?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, whatsapp

I have an issue using the new WhatsApp desktop app UWP from my Application.
With the previous version of the WhatsApp Desktop App and using this command from my C# Application

> whatsapp://send?phone=393331234567&text=Hello

Whatsapp used to open with the message ready to be sent, now this no longer happens with the new Whatsapp app, only the WhatsApp app opens but without the message I have to send, can anyone help me?
the same issue is with using RUN Command on Windows.
if you copy and paste the following row

> whatsapp://send?phone=393331234567&text=Hello

in Run Command of windows and press ok, the WhatsApp App Open, but nothing message is inserted.

Comment: you can found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use: https://wa.me/1XXXXXXXXXX
Don't use: https://wa.me/+001-(XXX)XXXXXXX

```
string number = "1XXXXXXXXXX";
string api = $"https://wa.me/{number}";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(api);
```

Comment: using your method not work, not set the text and phone number inside wa.

Comment: You can found any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, and I'm afraid there is no solution, the amazing thing is the nonexistent support and the fact that this page still states that it can be done. too bad nothing works.

https://faq.whatsapp.com/563219570998715/?cms_platform=iphone

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around until WhatsApp decide to fix the bug in their desktop version.

In short, first send the phone number request, then wait a second before sending the number and text parameter.

```
<a onclick="OpenWA()">Open WhatsApp Desktop</a>
<script>
    function OpenWA() {
        window.location = 'whatsapp://send?phone=70000';
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location = 'whatsapp://send?phone=70000&text=Hey';
        }, 1500);
    }
</script>
```

**N O T E !**
This only works for desktop, and not when using a mobile.
So my advice is to check if the user is using a mobile or desktop device.

Comment: you found a great solution, congratulations, you are the winner :-)