# Why has Whatsapp text command stopped working

Tags: whatsapp

I have an electron app where I am using the whatsapp shell command to send messages.
It doesn't send message, rather opens up the contact in whatsapp desktop and types the message. But this week, It has stopped typing the text. I am unable to find any announcement around this change from whatsapp.

The command:

```
shell.openExternal(`whatsapp://send?phone=+91${moobile}&text=${message}`)
```

Any idea why it stopped working and how to get it running again?

Comment: it's possible that the WhatsApp desktop app has recently been updated, and this change has caused the behavior you're seeing

Comment: I just answered this question in a different thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74843270/3073905